# How to add stylesheet to head for plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've looked through the [Action Hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and [Filter Hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and I can't find a function that will add scripts and stylesheets to the `<head>` Maybe I am not supposed to do it this way?

```
function juicyreviews_show_reviews(){
    # Link certain scripts and stylesheets in the head.
    # Like... masonry, jQuery, modernizr.js

    return "<div>I need scripts and styles.</div>";
}

add_shortcode('juicy_reviews', 'juicyreviews_show_reviews');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to queue these styles in your function, then you need to apply the action to that function.

```
function juicyreviews_show_reviews(){
    wp_enqueue_script('masonry', '/path/to/masonry.js');
    wp_enqueue_style('my_css', '/path/to/my_css.css');
}
```

Then you can bind to the `wp_head` action with your `scripts`. *note* only scripts/styles can reside in this function.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'juicyreviews_show_reviews');
```

Comment: Can `add_action('wp_head', 'juicyreviews_show_reviews');` somehow be bound to the shortcode? So it only puts associate plugin scripts in the head when the shortcode is used? Or do I just run `add_action('wp_head',...)` once and the scripts and styles get placed in the head on every page?

Comment: @broinjc You need to run it independent of the shortcode function.

Comment: So when wp_head is called, so is my function. Yes? I made a new function `juicyreviews_assets()` and put everything in there. And. It. Is. Working! Thank you.

Comment: er.. `wp_head` is an action. What is the difference between actions and functions?

Comment: @broinjc `wp_head` is a hook, an `action` is a method you can bind to so that you can make modifications to it in Wordpress. I'd highly suggest checking out [the Wordpress Codex for add_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)